# "rails generate controller ControllerName" not creating default 7 REST actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

If I run `rails generate controller ControllerName` I get an empty controller?  I can manually edit it to what I want but why does this seem to happen?  Is it not suppose to put the 7 default in there if I leave the options blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the default behavior for the controller generator. If you want the default actions, you will want to use `rails generate scaffold`.

Note that you can also pass the names of actions to the controller generator to generate blank actions. This takes care of setting up basic tests/views/etc, but you will need to write your own code for each action you define this way:

```
rails generate controller ControllerName action1 action2 etc
```

Comment: I did that first and the Controller was still blank.  That's why I was running `rails generate controller ControllerName`